# How to deal with XML document with optional nodes where node sequence is important

Tags: swift, xml, xmlmapper

I need to parse the following type of XML into a Swift Object:

```
<grandparent>
    <parent_1 attr1="a">
        <child_1 attr1="b"/>
        <child_2 attr1="c"/>
    </parent_1>
    <parent_2 attr1="a">
        <child_1 attr1="b"/>
        <child_2 attr1="c"/>
    </parent_2>
    <parent_3 attr1="a">
        <child_1 attr1="b"/>
        <child_2 attr1="c"/>
    </parent_3>
</grandparent>
```

Each of the parent nodes are optional but whatever order they are defined in above must be preserved in the final Swift object - in this case an array with parents 1,2,3 (if they were all present).

I'm not clear how to do this with XMLMapper. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a new tag:

```
<parents>
  <parent id=1>...
  <parent id=2>..,
</parents>
```

Set an id attribute.

You will get a parents element with parent children.

Sort the array by id:

```
array.sort(by: { $0.id < $1.id })
```

Comment: I don't control the XML, it can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since version [1.5.2](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper/releases/tag/1.5.2) of [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) you can preserve the order of the elements by using `nodesOrder` property of `XMLMap`. See the readme [here](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper#swift-42-and-unordered-xml-elements).

So, you can map your XML like:

```
class Grandparent: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var parent_1: Parent?
    var parent_2: Parent?
    var parent_3: Parent?
    var nodesOrder: [String]?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        parent_1 <- map["parent_1"]
        parent_2 <- map["parent_2"]
        parent_3 <- map["parent_3"]
        nodesOrder <- map.nodesOrder
    }
}

class Parent: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var attr1: String?
    var child_1Attr1: String?
    var child_2Attr1: String?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        attr1 <- map.attributes["attr1"]
        child_1Attr1 <- map.attributes["child_1.attr1"]
        child_2Attr1 <- map.attributes["child_2.attr1"]
    }
}
```

You can preserve the ordering by simply doing nothing more than ordinary mapping:

```
let grandparent = Grandparent(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Or you can change it manually:

```
let grandparent = Grandparent(XMLString: xmlString)
grandparent.nodesOrder = ["parent_1", "parent_3", "parent_2"]
```

If you have many parent elements and you can change your provided XML, you should probably use an array of `<parent>` elements and not `<parent_1>`, `<parent_2>` and `<parent_3>`

```
<grandparent>
    <parent attr1="a">
        <child_1 attr1="b"/>
        <child_2 attr1="c"/>
    </parent>
    <parent attr1="a">
        <child_1 attr1="b"/>
        <child_2 attr1="c"/>
    </parent>
    <parent attr1="a">
        <child_1 attr1="b"/>
        <child_2 attr1="c"/>
    </parent>
</grandparent>
```

In this case you can map it in an `Array<Parent>` and you don't have to worry about ordering:

```
class Grandparent: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var parents: [Parent]?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        parents <- map["parent"]
    }
}

class Parent: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var attr1: String?
    var child_1Attr1: String?
    var child_2Attr1: String?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        attr1 <- map.attributes["attr1"]
        child_1Attr1 <- map.attributes["child_1.attr1"]
        child_2Attr1 <- map.attributes["child_2.attr1"]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I have no control over XML so have to deal with what I get. My parent nodes can occur in any order e.g. p3,p3,p1,p2,p2,p1 and multiple times or none. I need to end up with an array that preserves the nodes in the order they appear in the XML as there's a time dimension to the data.

Comment: @JayJay There is a way of mapping the parent elements. (each in a different `Array<Parent>`, one array for `<parent_1>`, one for `<parent_2>` and so on) But, unfortunately, there is no way of keeping the correct order of the elements. Sorry. This is a really difficult XML to parse and use, given the fact that the elements of a `Dictionary` are unordered, now in Swift 4.2.

Comment: Ok @gcharita thanks for your help, much appreciated. I've solved my parsing issue by using SWXMLHash. It allowed me to examine the top level parent nodes and invoke an appropriate parser each and adding them to an array.

Comment: @JayJay it's nice that you found a workaround. SWXMLHash is a great pod. (I didn't know that it supports that)

Comment: @gcharita how best can I handle this scenario `<itunes:category text="Life & Love"/>`